# Postman Response Body "message" disappear

Tags: rest, postman

I am currently learning RESTFUL web service tutorial using postman software. However, I am not able to see the error message detail that was shown in my tutorial. May I know how can I get the "message" to be display in postman response body? Thank you.

[image]

Below show the example from my tutorial.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever backend framework you are using look for the Environment Debug variable and set it to **true** if you are using laravel go to env file and set APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: Hi, I am using Java Spring Boot for the backend framework. May I know if the APP_DEBUG you mention can be set in the setting of the ide or in the coding? Thank you.

Comment: i am not java developer but you can check this link https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-enable-debug-logging/ it is related to enable debugging in your environment

Comment: Thank you so much! I solve it by  adding 
server.error.include-message = always
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
in my "application.properties"